# Any ideas for an astronomy + ML project?

Tags: astrophysics, cosmology, fundamental-astronomy, data-analysis

I wish to do an astronomy related project which incorporates machine learning.Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: There are a bunch. One is the PLAsTiCC (https://www.kaggle.com/c/PLAsTiCC-2018) which was on Kaggle. The competition is already closed, but I think you can still get the dataset to play around with.

Comment: This is too broad. You need to find a specific question.

Comment: slightly related: [How might one approach using AI (convolutional neural network) to predict collisions in orbit?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/24488/12102)